# PHP Variable scope: Pass parameter by reference with default value to anonymous function?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to loop through a mysql result and run an anonymous function on each record, but I'm having some trouble with variable scope. The problem is part of a much bigger flow but I've created a simplified example here which demonstrates the issue simply:

```
function runLoop($some_mysql_resource){
    $res = 'RESULTS: ';
    sqlEach($some_mysql_resource, function($sql){
        $res .= $sql['id'].',';
    })
    return $res;
);
```

Is there any way to make the runLoop function above output the following without changing the logical flow?

```
RESULTS: 1,2,3,4,etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `$res` as an argument "by reference" to your callback using `use`

```
function runLoop($some_mysql_resource){
    $res = 'RESULTS: ';
    sqlEach($some_mysql_resource, function($sql) use (&$res) {
        $res .= $sql['id'].',';
    })
    return $res;
);
```

I assume that `$sql` is defined somewhere in your real code, and so will have scope

Comment: Wow, excellent - precisely what I was looking for in under a minute! Thank you Mark